# Add Yandex Map in android application

Tags: android, google-maps, yandex, yandex-maps, yandex-api

I want to add a **Yandex Map** into my android application.

The question can be seem a little long but that is because of  I shared all my codes. Thanks for your patience in advance.

I couldn't find much source compare to Google Maps naturally.

[I used this source](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android) First I wanted to run a simple sample. [So I used this sample.](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/blob/master/yandexmapkit-sample/src/ru/mapkittest/mylocation/MapMyLocationChangeActivity.java) 
Finally I achieved something. I don't get any error. But I also couldn't display the map. I only have some **squarred area** (chequered, checked) and one "**target icon**".  You can see the activity class code below.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import ru.mapkittest.R;
import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.*;
import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.location.MyLocationItem;
import ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.overlay.location.OnMyLocationListener;

/**
 * MapLayers.java
 *
 * This file is a part of the Yandex Map Kit.
 *
 * Version for Android © 2012 YANDEX
 *
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at http://legal.yandex.ru/mapkit/
 *
 */

public class MapMyLocationChangeActivity extends Activity implements     OnMyLocationListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapController mMapController;
LinearLayout mView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle("Title");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.showBuiltInScreenButtons(true);

    mMapController = mapView.getMapController();
    // add listener
        mMapController.getOverlayManager().getMyLocation().addMyLocationListener(this);

    mView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(MyLocationItem myLocationItem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Type " + myLocationItem.getType()+" GeoPoint ["+myLocationItem.getGeoPoint().getLat()+","+myLocationItem.getGeoPoint().getLon()+"]");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mView.addView(textView);
        }
    });


}

}
```

The following is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="gcm.b4deploy.com.yandexmap.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>


<ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:apiKey="myapikey" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I also added this line under dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
compile 'ru.yandex:yandexmapkit:2.4.2@aar'
```

And also added this block into outer build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/raw/maven/' }

    }
 }
```

Following screenshot is output from genymotion. What am I missing, why can't display the map. Actually the source that I gave above is in Russian so I tried to do as best I can but although I may missed something. **Any idea?** If there exist **another source or documentation** (in english ) that you may suggest to me about **how to add yandex map into android app**, I would love to see that. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run your application on a real device?

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Not yet, trying now. May take a time. I will let you know. BTW when I deleted the api key in layout file, it again worked as the same way. So I thought maybe the key is not activated or I dont know what does it mean?

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin I tried on real device again got same result, there is no map only there are squares.

Comment: The problem might be with you API key. Also, could you check if [Yandex Maps app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.yandex.yandexmaps&hl=en) is working on your devices?

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin in emulator Yandex Maps app is working. And in emulator I could display google maps inside my application without any problem. I got api key from this link. [link](https://tech.yandex.com/keys/get/?service=trnsl) I registered and got api key and pasted it into layout file as it is in samples from github link -> [link](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/blob/master/yandexmapkit-sample/res/layout/sample8.xml) I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that your link is correct way to obtain an access token. Please have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/198).

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Surprisingly new api key is not needed. I wrote 1234567890 as it is in github sample it worked :) Thank you so much you were the only helper =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. I sent an email to yandex support and they sent me api key and they said that the only way to get an api key is contacting with them.

[This is yandex support page.](https://yandex.com/support/common/feedback.xml)

Just fill the form and request for a mapkit api key. They return in two days.

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem first then I managed it with adding

`@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
    }`

and

`@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
    }` as mantioned [here](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/quickstart-docpage/)